# Magento 1.7 price filter error (Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'where clause')

Tags: magento-1.7

In my productlist, when I filter on price, I get this error.
Does anybody know, how to fix this?

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price'
>   in 'where clause'
>
> Trace:
>   0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>   1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>   2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>   3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
>   4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
>   5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(825):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>   6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>   7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225):
>   Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
>   8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211):
>   Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
>   9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1036):
>   Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
>   10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
>   11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Observer.php(78):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
>   12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338):
>   Mage_Review_Model_Observer->catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1311):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Review_Model_Observer),
>   'catalogBlockPro...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
>   15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(163):
>   Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
>   16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
>   17 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   18 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
>   19 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(85):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
>   20 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/domain/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(67):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
>   21 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('/var/www/vhosts...')
>   22 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/johans...')
>   23 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   24 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   25 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   26 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
>   27 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   28 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
>   29 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/domain/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(50):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
>   30 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('/var/www/vhosts...')
>   31 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/johans...')
>   32 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   33 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   34 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   35 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
>   36 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(159):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
>   37 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
>   Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
>   38 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
>   39 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   40 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   41 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   42 /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: It was a compatibly problem.
I had changed the price filter in Magento 1.6 
(app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/price.php)

In 1.7 this file has changed, so i had to change it also in the app/code/local directory.

Comment: Could you describe what do you have changed?

Comment: Well, first check why price.php is in your in local directory. After that, replace this file with the version in the core directory and edit it to your requirements.

Comment: Oh Royw, sorry. My Price.php is not at local pool, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I had roughly this error after upgrading; we are using Mana Pro.  Upgrading Mana Pro to the newest version addressed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

On line 114 in:

app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Resource/Filter/Price.php

Change:

```
$select->group($rangeExpr)->order("$rangeExpr ASC");
```

To:

```
$select->group($rangeExpr)->order($rangeExpr, "ASC");
```

This fixed my problem using Manadev Layered Navigation (Mage 1.9.1)