# Filter products without images in Magento

Tags: php, magento, filtering, magento-1.8, product

Requrement: We have a bunch of products with and without images. We only need to display products with images in the frontend.

What I did: I have tried almost all the SO resources like:

[Filter products without images on Magento frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578359/filter-products-without-images-on-magento-frontend)

[How can I find all products without images in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565377/how-can-i-find-all-products-without-images-in-magento)

[Hide Products without images magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244485/hide-products-without-images-magento)

and their various combinations with no luck.. I think something changed in the new version of Magento. I am using version  1.8.1.0

Is somebody able to shed some lights here?

UPDATE: On my debugging, I found out that

`->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))`

really worked. But an error occurs in layered price filter. I was thinking this is not working earlier.I am getting the error similar to: [Magento 1.7 price filter error (Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'where clause')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997912/magento-1-7-price-filter-error-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-e-min-pri)...

According to Royw's answer to the above question, I believe, we need to edit the file: Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/price.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Magento events. I added an observer for the event:

`catalog_product_collection_load_before`

which adds a filter to remove all the products without images when loading product collection. The observer is as follows:

```
public function filterProductsWithoutImages($observer) {
    if (isset($observer['collection'])) {
        $collection = $observer['collection'];
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => "no_selection"));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here we need to disable "Use Flat Catalog Product". For that:

Admin > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Product to "No"

Since this filtering is not compatible with the use of "Flat Catalog Product"

Product counts in search pages work fine with this.

Answer (score 0):

You tried this?

```
->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
```

Comment: On my debugging, I found out that this really worked. But an error occurs in layered price filter. I was thinking this is not working earlier.I am getting the error similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997912/magento-1-7-price-filter-error-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-e-min-pri... This is what is in error report: http://pastebin.com/1S5qyJdQ

Comment: According to Royw's answer, I believe, we need to edit the file: Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/price.php

Comment: @Binod, Can you accept the answer if it is useful to you?

Comment: @Charlie I am sorry, its actually not an answer. The code given by you is already mentioned in the links I have in my question. Though I appreciate your response

Comment: @Binod, Thank you, May be next time will help you.